# Embed images from a database table in an email using sp_send_dbmail (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sp-send-dbmail

I currently have a SQL Server 2005 database that sends HTML emails to various users, and I take advantage of the `@file_attachments` parameter to embed images in the email. I have the image files on the SQL Server itself, so the parameter refer to the absolute path of the images on the server.

We're now moving to SQL Server 2008 R2, which is nice, but the new server structure is locked down so I can't just drop image files on the server and point the `@file_attachments` parameter at them.

I'm looking at two possible solutions:

- Store the images in a database column of type `VARBINARY(MAX)` or `IMAGE`, and somehow point the `@file_attachments` parameter at that.  I don't see any way to do this, though.
- Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` with `FILESTREAM` and figure out the physical path to the file on the database server. Not sure if this is possible, but I suspect it is.

Has anybody tried this? Any other suggestions?

Thanks, Jim

Comment: Put the e-mail on your file/web server, and just use <img src> like you would in a web page?

Comment: That's missing the point: the images need to be embedded in the email, not external links.  See this for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663048/how-to-embed-image-in-html-and-send-html-as-email-by-msdb-dbo-sp-send-dbmail.

Comment: You know those won't always render, right? Making it about as reliable and predictable as external links.

Comment: I know, but it's still what I'm looking for.  Thanks

Comment: For option #1: `IMAGE` is a deprecated type, don't use it anymore. **Always** use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead